# How to find how much bytes were sent on fetch request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am fetching data from different API with javascript's fetch API. But how can I find out how many bytes are sent on each request for analytics?

The request could be in any method.
I know that I can get the amount of bytes received with
`response.headers["content-length"]`.
I need to find out a way to get the amount of bytes sent on the frontend (browser or mobile using React Native). Ideally, it would be the total size of the request, but just the size of the request body would be good enough.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think, what OP is asking, is to find out the size of a request body, ie the number of bytes sent from frontend to the backend ...

Comment: yes @derpirscher is right. I am asking for a way to  find out the number of bytes sent from frontend to the backend. Doesn't ```content-length``` of response header mean amount of data received from the request? @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @ImtiajBinAoual - That isn't what derpirscher said, though. :-) They said request *body*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `response.headers["content-length"]` is the size of the response (ie from backend to frontend) body. OP is asking the size of the **request's** body (ie from frontend to backend)

Comment: @derpirscher - I think you're right, or at least close (closer than I was). @​ImtiajBinAoual - 1. Do you want this information on the *sending* side (which I believe is the browser in your case, since you said `fetch`), or the *receiving* side (the server, if I understand you correctly)? 2. Do you want the **total** size of the request (including headers, cookies, etc.) or just the size of the request **body**?

Comment: 1. I want the information on the sending side (browser, mobile(react-native))
2.total size of the request would be great but only request body size would also work

Comment: @Kaiido thanks, I'll try out the post request solution. Currently I am needing this for a expo managed react-native project. So I don't think it's possible to set a ServiceWorker.

Comment: Actually forget about the ServiceWorker idea, that won't work, the headers aren't accessible there either.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value that will be set in the Content-Length header by reading the Request's body as text and checking the length of the returned string:

```js
(async () => {
  const formdata = new FormData();
  const file = new Blob(["data".repeat(1024)])
  formdata.append("key", file)
  const req = new Request("/", { method: "POST", body: formdata });
  // note that we .clone() the Request
  // so that we can still use the original one with fetch()
  console.log((await req.clone().text()).length);
  fetch(req);
  console.log("check the Network panel of your dev tools to see the sent header");
})();
```

However this only applies for requests where this header is sent, i.e not for GET and HEAD requests.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution that I used - a tiny middleware (I use `Express`):

```
const socketBytes = new Map();
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.socketProgress = getSocketProgress(req.socket);
    next();
});

/**
 * return kb read delta for given socket
 */
function getSocketProgress(socket) {
    const currBytesRead = socket.bytesRead;
    let prevBytesRead;
    if (!socketBytes.has(socket)) {
        prevBytesRead = 0;
    } else {
        prevBytesRead = socketBytes.get(socket).prevBytesRead;
    }
    socketBytes.set(socket, {prevBytesRead: currBytesRead})
    return (currBytesRead-prevBytesRead)/1024;
}
```

And then you can use `req.socketProgress` in your middlewares.

Comment: Nice! But the OP seems to be asking how to do this on the other end: *"... on the frontend."*